# error: GH008: Your push referenced at least 4 unknown Git LFS objects

Tags: git, object, reference, push, git-lfs

I have pushed some files over the LFS out of which I have lost at least 4 files when I changed the origin of the repository.

I am unable to push to the repository because the operation fails every time with this same error message:

```
error: GH008: Your push referenced at least 4 unknown Git LFS objects:
```

Is there any way to un-track or delete these files so that I can move ahead with pushing my data to the repository?